# Append "AND" clause to WP QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get a filter to work in Wordpress that will append a clause to the current query and only select results with a certain `meta_key` value.

I can't do it through `$args` because the way the theme is setup and uses other filters and hooks for post data.

I can get it to work perfectly using the following code:

```
function filter_where($where = '') {
    $where .= "AND post_date >= '2016-09-24' ";
    return $where;
}

add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

I understand that the meta data is in a different table, but not exactly sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

I found a way to do this... Here is the fix just in case someone runs into the same issue.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'posts_meta_array');

function posts_meta_array($query)
    {

    // IF IT IS AN ARRAY YOU HAVE TO SERIALIZE IT

    $meta_it = serialize(strval("1"));
    $query->set('posts_per_page', '6');
    $query->set('meta_key', 'access');
    $query->set('meta_value', $meta_it);
    $query->set('meta_compare', 'LIKE');
    }
```